# How do I notate b5 chords in roman numerals?

Tags: chord-theory, roman-numerals

I want to name the chord C<sup>♭5</sup> (i.e., C with a diminished fifth) in roman numerals; how would I do that? The key is C major. I am fairly sure it is I<sup>♭5</sup>, but I want to check.

Also, how do you name modal triads like C lydian (still in C)? Is there a more efficient way than something like I<sup>add♯4(no3)</sup>?

Comment: Why not VII5? I'm wondering if you're trying to use roman numerals in a context where they don't really fit. Music that has Lydian chords is less likely to be functional and roman numerals are more about function than anything else.

Comment: @codeb0i Assuming that you're using functional harmony (for which degree numeration is important for their harmonic role), all chords you're mentioning are *altered* chords, so they need a specific notation: considering that degrees normally follow tonality and mode, G♭ doesn't exist in C major and in C in general, so you have to specify the "exception": I♭5. I don't really like the term "modal triads", as it's ambiguous (C-F#-G *may* describe a lydian chord, but it could also define many others), but the concept remains: you have to specify all exceptions that are not the in standard triad.

Comment: Using regular text with no superscript , it is better to write C(b5) so as not to confuse it with (Cb)5 which is R-5. Also, the principles of constructing triads is no different in Lydian mode, a C chord is simply 1-3-5, or CEG. Anything beyond that can be done but is not a simple triad.

Comment: You really need to provide a longer passage where the chromaticism occurs and especially show enough that `C` major a key is _clear_. The closer to full notation, the better. Your description mixes flat 5 and sharp 4 which makes me think you aren't fully understanding how the chromaticism is functioning. More harmonic context is needed, the chords before and after at the very least.

Comment: @musicamante what do you mean by "specify all exceptions that are not in the standard triad"?

Comment: @codeb0i the conventional meaning of triad is a set of three notes at intervals of thirds from the root (considering reordering in case of inversions): II-IV-VI, V-VII-II, etc. While some theorists also call triads any group of three notes, regardless their intervals (thus allowing, for instance, I-II-VI), these are normally (and more clearly) referred to as "trichords". I understand that "lydian triad" may be acceptable for I-VI-V of a lydian scale, as it includes the fundamental aspects of that mode, it's ambiguous and inconsistent: for instance, what about modes that have characteristic »

Comment: » notes *outside* of the normal degrees of a standard triad? There is no difference between a dorian or aeolian triad, as there's none between ionian and mixolydian triads. Moreover, if a lydian replaces the third with the fourth, then, following the same concept, a locrian should also replace the third with the second, making things ambiguous if there's no proper context: without knowing inversions, C-F#-G can also be a F# locrian triad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a symbol for an augmented triad and one for a diminished triad.   Nothing, I think, specifically for a major triad with a flattened 5th.   But 'I(♭5)' would be understandable and unambiguous.

If a 'Lydian triad' is 1, ♯4, 5, I guess that would be 'I(sus♯4)' in Roman.

Comment: `sus` is something we’d expect from jazz style chord names. In roman numeral analysis this is not a common notation. Rather the general assumption is that 4 replaces 3, and 6 replaces 5. So in this case this would simply be `I 4#`. If we wanted to include the third we’d need to have `I 3 4# 5` (`I 3 4` by itself would be read as `I 3 4 6`).